# Display Images when view's charged

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic-view

I have a users list that contains their images.

I call first a Service in `ionViewWillEnter`

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.myservice.getUsers("")
    .subscribe(
    result => {
        _this.users= result.users;
    },
    error => {

    }
  )
}
```

And in each Item, I put the avatar_url in user's image src :

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
    <ion-img src="{{user.avatar_url}}"></ion-img>
    .......
</ion-item>
```

When the view's charged, nothing appears. I have to scroll down to display images.

Is there any method to display images at first ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `<ion-img>` tag then images are only loaded when they are visible on the device screen. Read the below from the manual at https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/img/Img/

> The ion-img component is similar to the standard img element, but it also adds features in order to provide improved performance. Features include only loading images which are visible, using web workers for HTTP requests, preventing jank while scrolling and in-memory caching.

If you want to avoid this then you can use a standard `<img>` tag instead

Comment: The images are not displayed. I have to scroll a little down or up to make them show. I do not know if I need to change something in `mycomponent.ts`, especially the function `ionViewWillEnter`

Comment: Even if you change the `<ion-img>` tag to be a simple `<img>` ?